# Dozer Mapping with Map and custom converter does not work

Tags: java, dozer

I want to map a class with a List of key-value pairs to a hashmap with dozer.

#### key-value pairs

This are the classes wich hold the key-value pairs

```
public class TExtensions {
    private List<SExtension> item;
    // Getter, Setter

public class SExtension {
    private String field;
    private String value;
    // Getter, Setter
```

And here are my two Beans

#### Class A

```
public class FooModel {
    private Map extensions;
    // Getter, Setter
```

#### Class B

```
public class FooWs {
    private TExtensions extensions;
```

#### My converter

```
public class ExtensionConverter extends DozerConverter<Map, TExtensions>    
{

public ExtensionConverter() {
    super(Map.class, TExtensions.class);
}

@Override
public TExtensions convertTo(Map source, TExtensions destination) {
    if (source != null && !source.isEmpty()){
        destination = new TExtensions();
        SExtension extension;
        for (Object key : source.keySet()){
            extension = new SExtension();
            extension.setField(key.toString());
            extension.setValue(source.get(key).toString());
            destination.getItem().add(extension);
        }
    } else{
        destination = null;
    }
    return destination;
}

@Override
public Map convertFrom(TExtensions source, Map destination) {
    if (source != null){
        destination = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (SExtension extension : source.getItem()){
            destination.put(extension.getField(), extension.getValue());
        }
    } else{
        destination = null;
    }
    return destination;
}
}
```

When I do the mapping via the configuration, it works well, but I can't use the feature, because the classes do not allways be part of the classpath as they are part of an optional module. So I have to put the mapping somewhere else and put it into a mapping file, but that does not work.

#### configuration

That works but I can't use it

```
<configuration>
    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="ExtensionConverter">
            <class-a>java.util.Map</class-a>
            <class-b>TExtensions</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</configuration>
```

#### Mapping file

This doesn't work but it seems to be the only option

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>FooModel</class-a>
    <class-b>FooWs</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="ExtensionConverter">
        <a>extensions</a>
        <b>extensions</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

When I do the Mapping with the mapping file (not the configuration) it maps from the Map to the TExtension, but not in the other direction. When I debug the Converter, both the source and the destination objects are null.

I've tested this with Dozer 5.5.1 and Dozer 5.4.0

Now I can think off two solutions for my problem

1. Load the custom Converter for the two types wheater the converter is in the classpath or not
2. Fix the problem with the mapping file

I would prefere the first solution as it seems to be cleaner and I don't have to duplicate the mapping files.

Do you have any ideas?